# Value in global context is empty in a specific case, not empty anywhere else

Tags: reactjs

This is my first React app. I have a global context, and it holds an array of objects, which are invoices. The global context is created like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useMemo } from 'react';

/**
 * Import the initial global state from the #root element,
 * which is in views/admin-pages.php
 */
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');
const initialState = JSON.parse( rootEl.getAttribute('initGlobalState') );

const GlobalContext = createContext();

function GlobalContextProvider({children}){

    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const contextValue = useMemo(() => [state, setState], [state]);

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { GlobalContext, GlobalContextProvider };
```

The global context provider wraps the entire app, so in any component I would have access to it by:

```
import { GlobalContext } from './../contexts/GlobalContext';
// ...
const [ globalState, setGlobalState ] = useContext(GlobalContext);
```

Since invoices are stored in the global context, I can access them with `globalState.invoices`. If I want to add some invoices I can do this:

```
const appendInvoices = ( invoices ) => {
    setGlobalState(globalState => ({
        ...globalState,
        invoices: globalState.invoices.concat(invoices)
    }));
}
```

This always works, but in the same file I have a timeout/interval set to look for paid invoices on the server:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let paymentsCheck = setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => checkForNewPayments(), 60000);
    }, 60000);
    return () => {
        clearTimeout( paymentsCheck );
    }
}, []);
```

When invoices have been paid that need to be updated, the paidInvoices is an object where the keys are numeric IDs of the invoices, and the values are timestamps:

```
const checkForNewPayments = () => {
    invModel.fetchNewPayments( response => {
        if(
            response.paidInvoices && 
            Object.keys(response.paidInvoices).length > 0
        ){
            updatePaymentStatuses(response.paidInvoices);
        }
    });
}
```

And finally, I'm trying to update the globalState with the changes:

```
const updatePaymentStatuses = ( paidInvoices ) => {

    // WHY IS globalState.invoices EMPTY ???
    console.log( globalState.invoices );

    const newInvoicesArr = globalState.invoices.map( invoice => {
        if( invoice.id in paidInvoices )
            invoice.paidAt = paidInvoices[invoice.id];
        return invoice;
    });
    if(newInvoicesArr.length > 0){
        setGlobalState(globalState => ({
            ...globalState,
            invoices: newInvoicesArr
        }));
    }
}
```

The problem is, at this function, globalState.invoices is empty, and that's impossible because there are invoices on the page. If globalState.invoices were truly empty, the page would render no invoices.

So, I'm hoping that somebody will see something that I'm not seeing. My question is, why would globalState.invoices be empty when it clearly isn't?

If you want to look at the entire file, it's available here:
https://bitbucket.org/skunkbad/simple-invoicing-w-stripe-wp-plugin/src/master/wp-content/plugins/simple-invoicing-w-stripe/admin-app/src/components/InvoicesTab.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is of closure, since the useEffect is called only on initial render, the globalState object that your `updatePaymentStatuses` method called from within `useEffect` is trying to access will always refer to the initial value since it gets the values from its lexical scope at the time of creation.

There are a few solutions to this

**First,** since you are using globalState within useEffect, you must pass it to dependency array of `useEffect` for the effect to closure to update when global state updates like

```
useEffect(() => {
    let paymentsCheck = setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => checkForNewPayments(), 60000);
    }, 60000);
    return () => {
        clearTimeout( paymentsCheck );
    }
}, [globalState]);
```

this however will not be a good idea always if you are setting state within useEffect and you are observing the same state. This might lead to an infinite loop

The **second solution** is to keep a reference of `globalState` using `useRef`

```
const [ globalState, setGlobalState ] = useContext(GlobalContext);
const stateRef = useRef(globalState);
useEffect(() => {
   stateRef.current = globalState;
}, [globalState]);

useEffect(() => {
    let paymentsCheck = setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => checkForNewPayments(), 60000);
    }, 60000);
    return () => {
        clearTimeout( paymentsCheck );
    }
}, []);

const updatePaymentStatuses = ( paidInvoices ) => {

    console.log( stateRef.current.invoices ); // use globalState from ref

    const newInvoicesArr = stateRef.current.invoices.map( invoice => {
        if( invoice.id in paidInvoices )
            invoice.paidAt = paidInvoices[invoice.id];
        return invoice;
    });
    if(newInvoicesArr.length > 0){
        setGlobalState(globalState => ({
            ...globalState,
            invoices: newInvoicesArr
        }));
    }
}
```